# Excel VBA Macro comma instead of point

Tags: vba, excel

i have a problem that excel makes me a ,(comma) instead of a .(point). I'm save the numbers from a cell in a string because i have to compare it with another string(maybe that's the problem), but when i change it in a numeric value the program doesn't work. It works like that:

`Dim releaseNumber As String`

`releaseNumber = tblRelease.DataBodyRange(j, 1)` In cell stands for example "1.5"

`If InStr(1, pruefRelease, releaseNumber, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then`

`Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A1").Value = releaseNumber` Writes "1,5" in cell A1

There are lines in between but they are unimportant.

While debugging in the last line it stands something like "1.5" in releaseNumber, so with a point. Thought the reason could be that German numbers are written like "1,5", but i work with English settings and the setting of my Format Cells is General.

Comment: Is there any solution that either the system/excel settings are German or English that it writes there it with a point? Because if i give it to someone with for example German settings i don't want that it changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem...

My guess is, that Excel thinks that you want a number in the cell and not a text.

my workaround:

```
Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A1").Value = "'" + releaseNumber
```

then it's a Text in the cell ...

does this help you?

BR
Haiko

Comment: it's a pragmatic solution, maybe someone finds a better one, but it should work for now, I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-format the cells before putting the value in them.

```
With Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A1")
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = releaseNumber
End With
```